# Having trouble initiating an array in a structure

Tags: c++, class

```
class CRA_Account {
    int tax[4];
    double refund[4];
    int SIN;
 public:
    CRA_Account();
 }

 CRA_Account::CRA_Account() {
     SIN = 0;
     tax[4] = { 0 };
     refund[4] = { 0 };
 }
```

When I create a object in main it'll set the SIN to 0 but won't do the same to the arrays. Can someone help why?

Comment: Arrays are not assignable.

Comment: Use the initializer list to construct attributes. What you're doing here is an assignment and that doesn't work with arrays.

Comment: Here https://ideone.com/CQBvR8 the part starting with the colon before the constructor body is called a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: 1) use the initializer list. 2) there's `std::fill`. 3) why not a `std::array`?

Comment: @Caninonos That worked. Thanks!

Comment: The Canadian Revenue Agency. Haven't done any work for them since they were the CCRA. I strongly recommend against storing the SIN as an integer. It's a string of digits, but not used as a number. You need all the digits so 000777888 getting chopped to 777888 because integers don't store preceding 0s can be a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tax[4] = { 0 };` is wrong at many levels..
One way to initlizie your class:

```
CRA_Account::CRA_Account():
   tax{0,0,0,0},
   refund{0,0,0,0},
   SIN{0}{
}
```

[Online](http://cpp.sh/7b5k4)

Try to have a look at [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)