# Int value is changing by itself after a for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, int

In my CRA_Account.cpp file my socialInsuranceNumber gets changed after  for

```
(j = 0; j <= max_name_length; j++) {
                given_name[j] = givenName[j];
            }
```

occurs.
example: If i enter 123123123 as my SIN, it gets changed to 123123148. The previous for loop that has

```
for (j = 0; j <= max_name_length; j++) {
                family_name[j] = familyName[j];
            }
```

doesnt change my socialInsuranceNumber value.

My code is:

w3_in_lab.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CRA_Account.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sict;

int main() {
    const int size = 1000;
    char familyName[size];
    char givenName[size];
    sict::CRA_Account myCRA;
    int sin;
    bool quit = false;
    if (sict::max_name_length + 1 > size) {
        cerr << "Increase size to value greater than " 
            << sict::max_name_length + 1 << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Canada Revenue Agency Account App" << endl
         << "=================================" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your family name: ";
    cin >> familyName;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Please enter your given name: ";
    cin >> givenName;
    cin.ignore();

    do {
        cout << "Please enter your social insurance number (0 to quit): ";
        cin >> sin;
        cin.ignore();
        if (sin != 0)
        {
            myCRA.set(familyName, givenName, sin);
            if (myCRA.isEmpty()) {
                cout << "Invalid input! Try again." << endl;
            }
            else {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            quit = true;
        }
    } while (!quit);
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Testing the display function" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    myCRA.display();
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

CRA_Account.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CRA_Account.h"
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
using namespace sict;
    void CRA_Account::set(const char* familyName, const char* givenName, int sin) {
        int j;
        if (sin >= min_sin && sin <= max_sin) {
            socialInsuranceNumber = sin;
            for (j = 0; j <= max_name_length; j++) {
                family_name[j] = familyName[j];
            }
            for (j = 0; j <= max_name_length; j++) {
                given_name[j] = givenName[j];
            }
        }
        else {
            socialInsuranceNumber = 0;
        }
    }

    bool CRA_Account::isEmpty() const {
        bool empty = false;
        if (socialInsuranceNumber <= 0) {
            empty = true;
        }
        return empty;
    }
    void CRA_Account::display() const {

        if (isEmpty()) {
            cout << "Account object is empty!" << endl;
        }
        else {

            cout << "Family Name: " << family_name << endl;
            cout << "Given Name: " << given_name << endl;
            cout << "CRA Account: " << socialInsuranceNumber << endl;

        }
    }
```

CRA_Account.h

```
#ifndef CRA_ACCOUNT_H
#define CRA_ACCOUNT_H

namespace sict {
    static int max_name_length = 40;
    static int min_sin = 100000000;
    static int max_sin = 999999999;

    class CRA_Account {
    public:
    void set(const char* familyName, const char* givenName, int sin);
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void display() const;

    private:
        char family_name[40];
        char given_name[40];
        int socialInsuranceNumber = 0;

    };

}
#endif
```

Comment: Use strings instead of char arrays. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This looks iffy `j <= max_name_length`

Comment: You should use `std::string` instead of `char array`, if you are required to use array, then use `strncpy()` instead of loop.

Comment: [Debug](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) and [minimze to relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting a question please!

Comment: [You're not the only person working on their taxes today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793373/having-trouble-initiating-an-array-in-a-structure). You should consider teaming up.

Comment: @user4581301: lol...

Comment: Warning: `cin >> familyName;` cannot handle names like Von Doom, and trust me. You don't want to piss that guy off.

Comment: Or names like "in Orbit"

Comment: With the `cin.ignore();`s I think you're trying to avoid this problem: [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction), but without `getline` in play (even though it should be) there is no need for the ignore. `>>` automatically discards preceding whitespace.

Comment: And same advice I gave the other dude, `socialInsuranceNumber`  is a number, but it's not used like a number. It is always and exactly 9 digits and 0 is a valid leading digit so, `static int min_sin = 100000000;` is not true and printing `socialInsuranceNumber` needs to prepend any leading 0s. If you really want to get fancy, there is a simple formula for validating SINs: multiply each digit by its corresponding digit in 121212121, sum the result, and if the numbers not divisible by 10, it's not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ and C arrays indexes are 0 based, which means index is valid in [0,n-1] range inclusive. Common pattern to iterate is:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < array_size; ++i )
```

some even prefer to write:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i != array_size; ++i )
```

so your loop:

```
for (j = 0; j <= max_name_length; j++) {
```

is wrong as it iterates over range [0,n] inclusive and leads to UB by accessing array with wrong index. In your case you copy part of memory where `socialInsuranceNumber` resides. So fix your loop and problem should disappear.

Note: you should use `std::string` instead of char array, this will not only simplify your code but make it less error prone. If you are required to use `char` array, then you should use `strncpy()` function from standard C library, not manual loop.

Comment: Is it really we have to answer _simple typo_ (well extended conception) questions like that over and over again? What about a comment and a close vote (or even better a dupe hammer)?

Comment: If you find dupe I will delete my answer, I swear

Comment: It's probably _too basic_ to find a better dupe than [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) :-P ... But regarding my initial comment: You're getting in the way of _roomba_ (I don't really want to go into [depth about that matter](https://www.today.com/home/when-roomba-met-dog-poop-man-s-poopocalypse-goes-viral-t101883) further).

Comment: @Andrew Sure `strncpy()` requires another argument specifying the maximum size of your target buffer.